# Do I have to get an online account to play the-crew?

Tags: the-crew

I just bought and downloaded The Crew game online to my ps4, and I am wondering why the button of creating a new game is not activated. Do I have to consider buying ps4 online voucher to play the game? or is playable offline?

Comment: The Crew is an [always-online game](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2013/06/21/ubisoft-confirms-that-the-crew-and-the-division-are-always-online/). I think you'll need online to begin playing it. I'm not sure how it quite works for PS4.

Comment: @TimmyJim Oh! do I have only to be connected to the internet or do I have to sign up for a monthly subscription account?

Comment: I found some more information - looks like you just need an internet connection and no subscription is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Crew is an [always-online game](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2013/06/21/ubisoft-confirms-that-the-crew-and-the-division-are-always-online/).

[According to Ubisoft](https://support.ubi.com/en-US/Faqs/000021930/Is-PS-or-Xbox-Live-Gold-required-XB1-PS4-X360-TC) (the game makers):

> Players with Xbox Live Silver or PlayStation Network accounts can play The Crew, enjoy Free Ride across the US map, play every mission and skills challenge, cross other players' paths, and participate in all the asynchronous activities that The Crew offers.
>
> However, in order to communicate with others and to dive further into the multiplayer experience with Co-op and PvP, either a Xbox Live Gold or PS+ membership will be required.

It looks like you should be able to play so long as you're connected to the internet on your console.  Playstation Plus should not be needed.